# How to use a secret file on a remote node

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a build process that relies on a secret file.  The file is copied from the secret area to a working directory and utilized during the build process.

Now that I need this to run on a remote node, the file can't be found by the build job.  I need some way to tell Jenkins when I run this job to make this secret file available to the slave.

Comment: As a followup, in actuality the file was being copied over to the slave.  Using withcredentials with a file does that for you.  My actual problem was an error being reported by one commandline tool was being eaten by another which was reporting an error that the file wasn't found, when in fact it was a keychain problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stash/unstash mechanism to transport the file to the node. See the below simplified version of a pipeline

```
node("master") {
  stash includes:"file.secret" name: "secret-file"
}
node("other-node"){
  unstash name: "secret-file"
}
```

Comment: I didn't need to use this to solve my problem, but it looks like a solid alternative for anyone where using withcredentials isn't viable.